# Jquery Cloning div on keypress

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a chunk of code :

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Begin cloned email section -->
    <div id="entry1" class="col-md-4 clonedInput_1">
      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div><!-- end #entry1 -->
    <!-- Button (Double) -->
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="btnAdd_1" name="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary" style="display:none"></button>
  <button type="button" id="btnDel_1" name="btnDel" class="btn btn-danger" style="display:none"></button>

<script>
  $('.clonedInput_1 div input').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32 || e.keyCode === 32) {
      $('#btnAdd_1').click();
      $('.clonedInput_1:last-child div input').val(null);
      $('.clonedInput_1:last-child div input').focus();
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Note : 
button with ID = 'btnAdd_1' cloning div with class = 'clonedInput_1'. keyCode 32 = 'Space' key on keyboard.

It DOES cloned the div, and it DOES focused on it, but when i press 'space' key on keyboard when i focused on the second div, it won't cloned himself. I have to manually focused back to the first div, and press 'space' to cloned.

Why ?, shouldn't the second cloned also have same class ? (so the selector in jquery can detect it.)

Comment: can you be please be clear with your problem..?

Comment: The selector only adds listener when it executes, use $(document).on("keypress", ".clonedInput_1",function(){..}) instead

Comment: wooogh, Awesome, thanks drunkwolf !, it answered my question.

Comment: btn, btn-primary, col-md-4? I wonder what framework this is. Should tag with bootstrap

Comment: I'll add it as an answer in case you want to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script only adds listener to the class when it executes, use

```
 $(document).on(
        "keypress",        
        ".clonedInput_1",
        function(){..}
    )
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.clonedInput_1:last-child div input').val("");
$('.clonedInput_1:last-child div input').focus();
```

instead of

```
$('.clonedInput_1:last-child div input').val(null);
```

This should take the focus on the last input field.